# Should 'templates' be a synonym for 'templating' and should 'auto-publish' be a synonym for 'publishing'?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

In looking at the current proposed [Tag Synonyms](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) there were two that stood out to me as being almost no-brainers:

- [templates](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/templates) is proposed as a synonym for [templating](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/templating)
- [auto-publish](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auto-publish) is proposed as a synonym for [publishing](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing)

Currently there are no questions tagged with either [templates](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/templates) or [auto-publish](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auto-publish) as the questions that did use those tags were retagged some time ago but I wanted to see if these proposed synonyms make sense to people?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at them yesterday too and was unsure, [templates](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/templates) as a synonym for [templating](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/templating) I think we can indeed just approve.

[auto-publish](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auto-publish) as a synonym for [publishing](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing) I still think is a bit weird. But considering somebody thought it was needed to create that tag, when we create it a synonym, then at least we will never see it anymore, so probably do that too.

I already approved [anguilla](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anguilla) and [gui](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui) as a synonym for [cme](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cme) and [xpm](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xpm) as a synonym for [experience-manager](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experience-manager) since those had gotten two votes already and had been discussed.

Comment: As I hadn't seen any discussions on those two tags and there doesn't seem to be much visibility into the synonym proposals unless you go a hunting for them I figured it is worth having the discussion here.

Comment: Yeah I agree, that indeed makes sense. If we still don't get response on this we can add the featured tag to your question so it's shown on the main site.

Comment: +1, I agree on [tag:templates] being a synonym for [tag:templating]. "Auto-publish" confuses me because it sounds more like a question or even part of an answer rather than a tag. Does the tag also depend on the *answer* (e.g. event system, workflow, etc)?

Comment: @AlvinReyes, there have been times where I've retagged a question based on the answers to it but in general I view the tags as just describing/classifying questions. The original question using 'Auto-publish' was http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/219/is-auto-publish-for-experience-manager-configurable it asks about auto publishing on XPM and I retagged it with publishing quite a while back.

Comment: I thought tagging was simple, but I'm starting to see it's more complex, classification isn't a simple task. Common mistake I see is ppl using keywords as tags, while all our tags are keywords, but not all keywords make good tags... I think we should look at how do we want to group our questions and base the tags on that, is it required to have a difference between auto-publish and publishing? Auto-publish for me is a typical keyword which does not qualify as a tag really, but since somebody created a tag from it, better to make it a synonym so others won't make the same mistake.

Comment: Ah I see. Useful perspective on the difference between keywords and tags. I agree and see how `auto-publish` is more of a keyword. The classification for questions about it would fall under `publishing` (and `experience-manager` in that example). We're not creating a "folksonomy" of keywords, but are classifying questions based on topics that interest the Tridion community.

Comment: Taxonomies can be hard. This is one of the reasons we've had a full time library scientist on staff for the past five years to manage the taxonomies we use in our Tridion implementation. Even with that we still experience the occasional issue with creating keywords that are too specific (or too general) to really be usable.  This is usually easier to see with a large corpus of source material as a keyword used once in a sample of 100,000 items stands out a bit more than a keyword used once in a sample of only 288 items.

Comment: Based on lack of any dissenting opinions I have gone ahead and approved these two synonyms.

Comment: @GlennStevens it seems I was rather late with my dissent.

Comment: @DominicCronin still trying to get a good idea on how long to keep these sorts of questions open. In any event, we can always reverse the synonym.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-publish isn't the same as publishing. It should have its own tag. But perhaps auto-publish-anti-pattern might be better.

Comment: We are not disputing whether it is different, but why would it need its own tag. I think it can be perfectly grouped under [tag:publishing], maybe added with [tag:automation]

Comment: It's about helping people to find what they are looking for. If I'm looking for auto-publishing, then I don't want to see every post related to publishing, which is what creating a synonym does for you. We are not discussing why it would need its own tag, but whether the existing tag has the same meaning as "publishing". So if some people tag with "Tridion" and others with "SDL Tridion", you want the result set to include everything. That's what synonyms are for. This case is entirely different.

Comment: You can't make a tag for every word used in a question, that defies the logic of tagging. I agree that auto-publish and publishing isn't as clear and obvious as Tridion and SDL Tridion, but both are questions about publishing. If somebody searches for [auto publish](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/search?q=auto+publish) this question will still be found and its grouped under publishing by its tag.

Comment: Of the three items that show up when you search for auto-publish 1 is about autopublishing for preview in XPM, one about automating the publishing of specific pages and 1 about automating the publishing of deeply nested components. All three slightly different takes on automatic publishing maybe 'auto-publish' is an ok tag to use although I wonder if Bart's suggestion of such questions being tagged with both publishing and automation is a better approach?

Comment: I'd agree that tagging with both would be correct. Auto-publishing is publishing, just not the other way round.